# opencv get fps in variable

Tags: android, opencv

I'm new in developing on Android. I want to make an app with OpenCV.
For my app I want to have the FPS of the preview stored in a variable. I found a class in the OpenCVLibrary folder called FpsMeter, but when I call fpsmeter.init(), my app crashes. I tried different things, like setting

```
cameraBridgeViewBase.enableFpsMeter();
```

or

```
cameraBridgeViewBase.disableFpsMeter();
```

or

```
fpsmeter.setResolution(320, 240);
```

But it crashes every time.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

```
package be.anton.OpenCV_test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.FpsMeter;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;
    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback;
    FpsMeter fpsMeter;
    Mat mat1;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cameraBridgeViewBase = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.cam);
        cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        cameraBridgeViewBase.enableFpsMeter();
        cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                // super.onManagerConnected(status);
                switch (status) {
                    case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS: {
                        cameraBridgeViewBase.enableView();
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        fpsMeter.init(); // when I add this line my app crashes

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OpenCV could not be loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (cameraBridgeViewBase != null) {
            cameraBridgeViewBase.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cameraBridgeViewBase != null) {
            cameraBridgeViewBase.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mat1 = inputFrame.rgba();
        return mat1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mat1.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mat1 = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share error log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I created my own FPS meter. This is the code:

The variables I use:

```
Textview txt1;
int mFPS;
long startTime = 0;
long currentTime = 1000;
```

Set this in onCreate():

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
     }
});
```

And this is my onCameraFrame():

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mat1 = inputFrame.rgba();
    //Log.i(TAG, mat1.get(128, 128).toString());


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (currentTime - startTime >= 1000) {
                txt1.setText("FPS: " + String.valueOf(mFPS));
                mFPS = 0;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mFPS += 1;

        }
    });
    return mat1;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why no one upvoted. This piece of code helps. Thanks. Could you explain why the need for 'runOnUiThread'?

Comment: Just because I cannot access TextViews from onCameraFrame(). In other words txt1.setText() needs to be in the UIThread. I don’t know what you want to do but I’m using the Fotoapparat library now, which is really easy to work with. Hope this helped.